# Не видно элементов управления Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, controls

Первый раз работаю с `Android Studio`. Столкнулся с вот такой проблемой. Переношу из списка элементов управления на экран, но они почему-то не отображаются. Немогу понять в чём проблема. Может что-то в коде прописать нужно?? Вот скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нету в виртуальном смартфоне элементов. Я их добавил но их не видно

Comment: в ответ пожалуйста. Отмечу как принят

Comment: Лучше я оставлю здесь комментарий со [всеми вариантами решения](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34499839/7566397) этой временной проблемы/ Через некоторое время баг будет неактуален